# symfony get form attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I know that it is dumb question to ask but I need to know can I get form widget attributes through PHP I mean not a value but id, class or even parent or child. If I set them.

```
<label name = '{{ item.modulePath }}' id = 'main' class = 'menu_label' **parent = ''** **childs = ''**>{{ item.modulePath }}</label>
```

If it is not possible then how can I make JS function before form validation and post array to the form as value?

```
<form action="{{ path('menu_manage') }}" method="post">
```

Yes I could get values and submit form to JS and then by JS get all attributes and then through ajax send it to a PHP handler. But it would be longer, because I will need to include all components that have this action to the handle information to place where I need it.

Here is an example how to realize it

> http://symfony2forum.org/threads/5-Using-Symfony2-jQuery-and-Ajax

Answer (score 1):

You can call `get()` method on form field in template, e.g. having a form in `form` with field `item`:

```
{{ form.item.get('id') }}
```

The class - only if set - can be retrieved like this:

```
{{ form.item.get('attr').class }}
```